# how get property of object in array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

i use a some web service and data back in $res 
with print_r($res);

result :

> stdClass Object ( [Status] => 1000 [Information] =>
>   {"Products":{"TrafficCard":[{"Product":{"service_id":"6","name":"مجوز
>   عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 8
>   صبح","plan_name":"TC-8","price":"24000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"6","name":"مجوز
>   عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 10
>   صبح","plan_name":"TC-10","price":"18000","existence":true}}],"GiftCard":{"iTunes":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آیتونز 10
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-10","price":"38000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آیتونز 15
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-15","price":"55000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آیتونز 25
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آیتونز 50
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"Microsoft":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت مایکروسافت 25
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Microsoft-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت مایکروسافت 50
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Microsoft-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"GooglePlay":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت گوگل پلی 10
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-10","price":"38000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت گوگل پلی 15
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-15","price":"55000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت گوگل پلی 25
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت گوگل پلی 50
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"Amazon":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آمازون 5
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-5","price":"18000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آمازون 10
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-10","price":"36000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت آمازون 25
>   دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-25","price":"88000","existence":true}}],"XBox":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"اکانت
>   Gold یک ساله Xbox
>   Live","plan_name":"GC-XBox-1Y","price":"216000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"اکانت
>   Gold سه ماهه Xbox
>   Live","plan_name":"GC-XBox-3M","price":"91000","existence":true}}],"PlayStation":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت 10 دلاری PlayStation
>   Network","plan_name":"GC-PlayStation-10","price":"38000","existence":true}}],"PlayStationPlus":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت
>   کارت سه ماهه PlayStation
>   Plus","plan_name":"GC-PlayStationPlus-3M","price":"70000","existence":true}}]},"Antivirus":{"Eset":[{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"آنتی
>   ویروس موبایل نود
>   32","plan_name":"AN-Eset-MOB-1U","price":"20000","existence":true}}],"BitDefender":[{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"آنتی
>   ویروس موبایلی بیت دیفندر
>   2014","plan_name":"AN-BitDefender-MOB-1U","price":"25000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"بیت
>   دیفندر Plus
>   2014","plan_name":"AN-BitDefender-PC-1U","price":"65000","existence":true}}]}}}
>   )

i need all product in array :
like

```
TrafficCard {
serviceid =>  ...
name => ....
plan_name => ... 
price => ....
existence => ....
}
```

also this for 
Gift Card,Antivirus,XBox,Playstation and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function object_to_array($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $data;
}

$json = '{"Products":{"TrafficCard":[{"Product":{"service_id":"6","name":"مجوز عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 8 صبح","plan_name":"TC-8","price":"24000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"6","name":"مجوز عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 10 صبح","plan_name":"TC-10","price":"18000","existence":true}}],"GiftCard":{"iTunes":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آیتونز 10 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-10","price":"38000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آیتونز 15 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-15","price":"55000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آیتونز 25 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آیتونز 50 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-iTunes-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"Microsoft":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت مایکروسافت 25 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Microsoft-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت مایکروسافت 50 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Microsoft-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"GooglePlay":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت گوگل پلی 10 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-10","price":"38000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت گوگل پلی 15 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-15","price":"55000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت گوگل پلی 25 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-25","price":"91000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت گوگل پلی 50 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-GooglePlay-50","price":"185000","existence":true}}],"Amazon":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آمازون 5 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-5","price":"18000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آمازون 10 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-10","price":"36000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت آمازون 25 دلاری","plan_name":"GC-Amazon-25","price":"88000","existence":true}}],"XBox":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"اکانت Gold یک ساله Xbox Live","plan_name":"GC-XBox-1Y","price":"216000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"اکانت Gold سه ماهه Xbox Live","plan_name":"GC-XBox-3M","price":"91000","existence":true}}],"PlayStation":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت 10 دلاری PlayStation Network","plan_name":"GC-PlayStation-10","price":"38000","existence":true}}],"PlayStationPlus":[{"Product":{"service_id":"7","name":"گیفت کارت سه ماهه PlayStation Plus","plan_name":"GC-PlayStationPlus-3M","price":"70000","existence":true}}]},"Antivirus":{"Eset":[{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"آنتی ویروس موبایل نود 32","plan_name":"AN-Eset-MOB-1U","price":"20000","existence":true}}],"BitDefender":[{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"آنتی ویروس موبایلی بیت دیفندر 2014","plan_name":"AN-BitDefender-MOB-1U","price":"25000","existence":true}},{"Product":{"service_id":"8","name":"بیت دیفندر Plus 2014","plan_name":"AN-BitDefender-PC-1U","price":"65000","existence":true}}]}}}';

echo print_r(object_to_array(json_decode($json)),true);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Products] => Array
        (
            [TrafficCard] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Product] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 6
                                    [name] => مجوز عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 8 صبح
                                    [plan_name] => TC-8
                                    [price] => 24000
                                    [existence] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Product] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 6
                                    [name] => مجوز عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 10 صبح
                                    [plan_name] => TC-10
                                    [price] => 18000
                                    [existence] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )


etc...
```

Comment: thanks but how can i get only `[Product] => Array
                                (
                                    [service_id] => 6
                                    [name] => مجوز عبور از طرح ترافیک از ساعت 8 صبح
                                    [plan_name] => TC-8
                                    [price] => 24000
                                    [existence] => 1
                                )`

Comment: For example:  `$tmp = object_to_array(json_decode($json));
echo print_r (  $tmp["Products"]["TrafficCard"][0] ,true);
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast it as array

```
$trafficCardArray = (array) $stdClass;
```

Or with json

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => {"Products":{"TrafficCard":[{"Product":{"service_id".... ! not help with `$trafficCardArray = (array) $stdClass;`

Comment: yeah you have to build the array yourself after processing that json. look at weinerks object_to_array function